# SVN subversive configuration

Tags: svn, ubuntu, subversive

I installed subversive plugins and JavaHL connector in my eclipse, is there any required installation else?

I am running in Ubuntu, If i want to be SVN server, I should install SVN in ubuntu for creating repository?

RGDS

Answer (score 0):

To create a new repository enter:

```
mkdir /home/user/myrepo/
svnadmin create /home/user/myrepo/
```

Ubuntu might tell you to install the subversion package:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

One [example](http://queens.db.toronto.edu/~nilesh/linux/subversion-howto/) and a few [more...](http://www.google.hu/search?q=subversion+tutorial)